# Таблица квадратов

Tags: python

Напишите функцию squared(a, b, k), которая выводит на экран таблицу квадратов для чисел от a до b, при этом не нужно выводить квадраты чисел кратных k. Если такое число встречается, его нужно пропустить, вывод переходит к следующему числу.
Строки формируются так. Берем исходное число и возводим в квадрат все числа, от него и до числа, в котором последняя цифра на 1 меньше, чем в исходном. Затем переходим на следующую строку. В ней нужно будет возводить в квадрат число, в котором десятков на 1 больше, чем в исходном, а единиц столько же. Например, если надо начать с 14, то заканчиваем строку на 23, возведенным в квадрат. А следующая строка начнется с квадрата числа 24. Если, конечно, квадраты этих чисел не кратны k.
Для каждого числа при выводе отводится 4 символа и один символ пробела разделяет столбцы.

Не до конца понял как решать данную задачу:

```
def squared(a, b, k):
    n = 1
 
    for i in range(a, b + 1):
 
        if i % k != 0:
            print(f"{i * i:<4}", end=' ')
        n += 1
 
        if n > k:
            n = 1
            print()
```

Не проходит второй пример

[image: примеры:]

Comment: Ну, кстати, либо второй пример ошибочный, либо описание задачи ошибочно. 33 не делится на 9, при этом квадрат 33 не выведен.

Comment: @CrazyElf 33**2 = 1089, 1089/9 = 121

Comment: @AnatolyKritskiy "при этом не нужно выводить квадраты чисел кратных k" - "чисел, кратных", а не "квадраты, кратные", формулировка задачи неправильная, значит.

Comment: @CrazyElf "Если, конечно, квадраты этих чисел не кратны k.". сам долго вчитывался, чтоб понять :)

Comment: @AnatolyKritskiy А, да. Дальше по-другому написано. Всё сделали, чтобы запутать ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
def squared(a, b, k):
    res = [ [j ** 2 for j in range(i, i+10) if j**2 % k != 0] for i in range(a,b+1,10) ]

    for line in res:
        for num in line:
            print(str(num).ljust(5), end=' ')
        print()
```

Более читаемое/понятное формирование массива:

```
res = []
for i in range(a,b+1,10):
    res.append([])
    for j in range(i, i+10):
        if j**2 % k != 0:
            res[-1].append(j**2)
```

Comment: хотя можно даже не формировать массив, а сразу отпечатывать генерирующиеся значения

Comment: squared(22, 64, 5) выводит числа до 5041, а нужно до 4096

Comment: Ты забыл при составлении списка сделать условие, чтобы число не было больше b**2, в условии задачи написано "выводит на экран таблицу квадратов для чисел от a до b". А так спасибо большое за решение))

Comment: @DEVOURING да-а, промахнулся, согласен :) нужно добавить еще условие в if или как то переиграть аргументы range во вложенном цикле

Comment: @DEVOURING только сейчас понял, можно было просто сделать список с квадратами, а выводить уже по 10 цифр, решение проще и мудрить не нужно